# Fun problem: Dividing a dataset into parts depending on mean value

Tags: matlab, filters

Ok, so I have some recorded data over several hours that looks like this (values on y, time on x).
See this image [http://imgur.com/fdakUlk](https://imgur.com/fdakUlk)
I need a way to use matlab to divide the data into sections depending on their mean value. The sections needs to be atleas a couple of hours. Just by looking at the data they can easily be spotted, see this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlxVN.jpg
Is there a good method of doing this? What do I need to research?

Thanks

Comment: Can you put the actual data up as a .mat file?

Comment: For reference, this problem is called [time series segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-series_segmentation)

Answer (score 1):

Try total variation denoising. Here I found a piecewise constant toolbox: http://www.maxlittle.net/software/pwctools.zip

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be much help to you, and, I haven't coded in matlab in a while (I could probably try to write some code which will allow this). Would the following not work?:

1) Split the data into segments of say 256 (256 samples in each data block)

2) Calculate the mean value of each block

3) Have a threshold value (Maybe look up dynamic threshold)

4) If the mean value `>=` OR `<=` to the threshold, determine what to do with it.

Please could you elaborate "their mean value", I assume you mean the `mean` value for each block, and, not the entire signal?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

1. Cluster the data (say using Otsu's thresholding method). This gives a temporal set of binary values
2. Use morphological operations like Opening, Closing, Erosion, and Dilation to determine end points of relevant lengths.

Sorry, I don't do matlab, but in Mathematica that would be pretty straightforward to implement.